# differentiate between make and package in Electron Forge config

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

I have an Electron Forge config file set up with many options and it all works automagically and beautifully (thanks Forge team!!). But I have found certain situations where I might want to handle a bare `npm run package` differently than a full `npm run make` (which as I understand it runs the `package` script as part of its process). Is there any way to programmatically detect whether the `package` action was run direct from the command line rather than as part of the `make` process, so that I can invoke different Forge configuration options depending? For example sometimes I just want to do a quick build for local testing and skip certain unnecessary time-consuming steps such as notarizing on macOS and some `prePackage`/`postPackage` hook functions. Ideally I'm looking for a way to do something like this in my Forge config file:

```
//const isMake = ???
module.exports = {
    packagerConfig: {
        osxNotarize: isMake ? {appleId: "...", appleIdPassword: "..."} : undefined
    },
    hooks: {
        prePackage: isMake ? someFunction : differentFunction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by `process.argv[1]`:

```js
let isMake;
if (process.argv[1].endsWith('electron-forge-make.js') {
  isMake = true;
} else {
  isMake = false;
}
module.exports = {
  // ...
}
```

When calling `process.argv`, it returns an array with two strings: The first one with node.js directory and the second one with electron forge module directory.
The make module ends with `electron-forge-make.js` and package module ends with `electron-forge-package.js`. So you can look at the end of it and determine whether it's package or make.